# Arduino - storing values from FRAM into a buffer

Tags: c++, arduino

In need to read bytes off of a [FRAM](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1895) module and store them into a buffer.  The example I have for reading values off the FRAM module is this:

```
uint8_t value;
  for (uint16_t a = 0; a < 32768; a++) {
    value = fram.read8(a);
    if ((a % 32) == 0) {
      Serial.print("\n 0x"); Serial.print(a, HEX); Serial.print(": ");
    }
    Serial.print("0x"); 
    if (value < 0x1) 
      Serial.print('0');
    Serial.print(value, HEX); Serial.print(" ");
  }
```

How would I go about storing these values into a buffer?

Comment: Vinicius's answer should be what you are looking for, anyway be aware that you probably shouldn't save ALL the FRAM contents, since they are 32k of memory (all the common arduino boards have AT MOST 32k of RAM, with the exception of the due)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the first ten values from memory and storing it in a buffer

```
uint8_t buffer[10];

for (uint16_t a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
  buffer[a] = fram.read8(a);
}
```